# Blender for scientific meshing

Tags: mesh

I'm pretty new to Blender. I'm trying to use it for scientific meshing (particulary for Boundary Element Method).

Here is my workflow right now:

- I draw my object in my CAD software (Fusion 360).
- I export it in `.obj` and I import it in blender.
- After some modification of the mesh in Blender I export it in `.obj`.
- Finally I import it in my scientific tool.

Now that you have some backgroung here is what I'm trying to do in Blender:

1. I need to separate my object into different part. (The scientific tool is able to recognize group in the `.obj`.)

For now I'm doing it by selecting the faces of one part in Edit mode and then press `P` to separate into a new object. But it seems that different objects can't share vertices. So if I'm modifying the mesh (for example by dissolving a vertex) of one object, its boundary will not match the other part and it results into a hole in my model. So how can i linked vertices?

2. I need to reduce the size of the mesh

From the CAD software, the mesh is very dense. This can results to very long computation. therefore i would like to reduce its size.
For now, I select the faces, dissolve it and then poke it.
I'm able too get from this :

[image]

To this:

[image]

Which is way better for my computation. But i would like to get less point. A solution could be to select one out of two vertices and dissolve it. But selecting manually the vertices is very long. Is there anyway to do it automatically. i tried the decimate modifier but i can't figure how to make it work. (maybe it's because my object is a plane and not a volume).
And as I said earlier, if i dissolve a vertex, the corresponding vertex from other part aren't modified and therefore i have a hole in my model.

and last question : is there anyway to perform a uniform remesh? I mean a remesh where all triangles are approximately the same size. This is not mandatory right now but it can be useful for particular cases.

Thanks!

Comment: Try the _Decimate_ modifier again - I would recommend setting it to "Planar" first - you need to be in _Object Mode_ in _Wireframe Preview_ to see it in real-time (without applying the modifier).

Comment: If that isn't what you're looking for, maybe try a _Remesh Modifier_ set to "Sharp" (Octree depth 6 or 7) - this will make the mesh into even(ish) quads - apply the _Remesh_, then add a _Triangulate Modifier_ to make the quads in to (relatively) even triangles.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it helps a lot. But I still have trouble with the remesh modifier.  I have a hole like this in my model (https://imgur.com/a/udaWlsm) and the remesh modifier is filling it. Any idea how to solve this?